# re installing pip into a virtual enviroment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was trying to upgrade pip in a virtual environment, but the process failed and now I don't have pip in the virtual environment.

So when in my virtualenv, I call pip it is not installed.

```
    (.tensorflowenv) PS D:\MyData\TestCode\TestTensorflow> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\MyData\TestCode\TestTensorflow\.tensorflowenv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried to instal it using get-pip but it also failed.

```
(.tensorflowenv) PS D:\MyData\TestCode\TestTensorflow> python get-pip.py
C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I (re) install pip in virtual environment?

Comment: It's probably easiest to just recreate the virtual environment than to try and fix the broken one.

Comment: @chepner I installed a lot of packages into it. is there an easy way to reinstall them after recreating virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

### How to install PIP

If you have not yet restored the virtual environment I will give you some steps to attempt to reinstall PIP on your system.

1. Download a script containing a recent version of PIP from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

2. Open the system terminal
3. In the terminal, use `cd` to go to the folder where you saved the file downloaded in step 1
4. Now run the file: `py -3 get-pip.py`
5. Update PIP to the latest version using the following command: `py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
6. Displays the installed PIP version: `pip --version`

I hope I was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual environment, and inside that, run

```
pip freeze --path /path/to/your/old/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages > requirements.txt
```

(replacing `python3.8` with whatever the appropriate subdirectory name is)

Then run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

In the future, keep `requirements.txt` up to date to make it easy to spin up a new virtual environment as necessary for your project.